# Does my question on static linking need improvement?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, question-quality

A few weeks ago, I asked [What's the difference between “statically linked” and “not a dynamic executable”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61553723/7509065), which is currently at +0/-2 votes. To me, it seems like a perfectly clear and reasonable question, especially given what the answer turned out to be. Is there something wrong with this question that I don't see? If so, what is it?

(Note: I was hit by not-yet-reversed serial downvoting recently, and at least one of the downvotes came at a time consistent with that attack, but given there's another downvote and also no upvotes, I'm not 100% sure that I'm not just missing something obvious.)

Comment: Looks fine to me

Comment: lacks in research and if the first commenter suggests a canonical answer, if can't be that unusual or good question.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica I think an expert explicitly saying “this question creates a good opportunity for a canonical answer (because one doesn’t exist yet)” is the *best* kind of Q. +1’d it.

Comment: @nbk: That's the opposite of what my comment says.  I wrote that the question should become the canonical Q&A for that, because PIE executable are relatively new and I don't remember seeing a question about how `ldd` classifies them before.

Comment: to ask why people downvote, is **unanswerable** , it doesn't matter if the majority finds this a god question or not. o wouldn't downvote it at once, but would check if this question wasn't answered before. seems to me that i never encountered such a thing as not an dll. A canonical question, is for me something that a question comes often again and again and  don't need to be posted in length again and again. and usually they have much more answers and also controversil points

Comment: @nbk can you point out where the question ask about reasons for votes? As I read it the question it uses voting pattern as possible indication of an obvious problem with the question and OP tries to find one. (The linked question itself looks reasonably asked to me and since I don't know tech that would be "skip" in the review queue)

Comment: @nbk: *Canonical* doesn't have to mean FAQ or multiple answers, only authoritatively answered and a good duplicate target.  Perhaps that's not standard usage.  Regardless, discussing the meaning of the word "canonical" is a tangent of a tangent: this is a question I haven't seen asked before, and I've read (almost?) every x86-64 / assembly question on SO since ~2015 and have gold badges in x86-64, gcc, and assembly.  (And `-pie` wasn't the default before 2015).  Also, it's not about DLLs or libraries at all; it's a GNU/Linux question about executables and what `ldd` says about them.

Comment: "Difference between" is a pretend question & unanswerably vague & reflects lack of research. "especially given" suggests you don't really believe "perfectly". "difference between" is a different question than the rest of the post.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't understand the voting at all.  It's asking why `ldd` says what it does, which is a perfectly reasonable question regardless of the answer.  The question has a very compact bug-free MCVE, and shows the build commands.  Formatting is also fine.

The fact that it has an interesting (IMHO) answer related changes in the last few years (PIE executables, which most tutorials predate) is just icing on the cake, and why I bothered to write a long answer instead of a short one.

This is very nearly the platonic (socratic?) ideal of a good SO question: has a specific non-obvious answer with future value for other readers wondering the same thing.  Answering questions like this (that have future value) are why I bother to wade through the sludge of so many boring other questions that *are* obvious.

**The one thing it's maybe missing is info about what OS you ran these on, e.g. a distro name / version.**  That hardly justifies the downvotes without comments, especially *after* the question is answered.  So IDK if that was what any of the downvoters were thinking.  Comments are exactly for that kind of feedback of specific problems with posts.

I added the [linux](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linux) just now because the question (and answer) are likely specific to modern GNU/Linux distros that configure GCC with `-pie` as the default.  (Other OSes use different object-file formats.)  If there was room for more tags, I'd also add back in the [linker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/linker) tag, and maybe [glibc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/glibc) because that's where this version of `ldd` is from.

The fact that it's Linux is already implied by the `mov $60, %eax` / `syscall`; MacOS uses different call numbers, and a Windows system would make `a.exe` not `a.out`, not pass an arg in EDI, and other differences.  Possibly there's a *BSD where this could work, but the other symptoms are perfectly explained by this being a GNU/Linux system with glibc and other GNU user-space..

But anyway, the only thing I can see at all wrong with the question is lack of info about what system this was run on.  It didn't seem like a problem to me at all because I'm also using GNU/Linux, and didn't notice that was left implicit.

The question is nicely formatted with a good title so I was able to fully grok the question and start in on writing an answer in seconds after looking at it, not having to read every word like some questions where the key details are much harder to spot.

Comment: "Difference between" is a pretend question where the asker hasn't researche to find out what the things are & there is no clear criteria for answering. So it merits downvoting. Asking for what 2 things mean is 2 questions so that & the lack of criteria for when it has been answered means it's not focused. If they gave their understandings & expectations with justifications & MRE that could be on-topic.

Comment: @philipxy: I'm guessing you don't understand what the question is about and are just objecting to the phrasing.  It's 100% a real question that's not easy to research, about the messages that `ldd` uses for programs with no shared libraries without / with `gcc -static`.  Perhaps there's a better way to phrase this like "why does ldd say ...", but I'm having a hard time coming up with a title that isn't a whole paragraph.  I did add `ldd` to the title.  Splitting this up into two questions would have been terrible because they're only interesting in contrast to each other.

Comment: @philipxy: I see your point that the title makes it *look* like it's not going to be a good question, but you're judging a book (or a pamphlet given the length) by its cover if you actually follow through and vote based on that.  And if you're telling other people how to vote on questions in tags you're not familiar with based on that, then that's even worse.  Re: expectations: I thought that was obvious: why does `gcc -static` *stop* `ldd` from calling it a static executable?  And why can there be two different kinds of executables without any shared libraries?

Comment: The question is, why the linked question might merit downvotes. It asks what it asks & not what it could ask & it doesn't reflect research. Also there's nothing about gcc or that flag etc that makes it an exception. One could write a helpful canonical answer to a poor question of say, how does x work?, but that doesn't make it a good question. Moreover when people are stuck it is usually on some misconception & a canonical answer does not address their misconception, the question if researched & pinned down. It's yet another presentation to misinterpret; for the misconception, a shotgun blast.

Comment: @philipxy: It's asking about what `ldd` means when it says those two different outputs.  Those aren't abstract terms that someone would have to know, they come directly from the output of a common tool.  *That's* what makes it ok to phrase the question that way.

Comment: There is literally nothing wrong with "what is the difference between...?" questions. They're not "fake" or "pretend" questions, or anything else that has been leveled at them in this discussion. The only thing that could potentially go wrong with "what is the difference between...?" questions is that the answer is too complex, meaning that they cannot be reasonably answered in our format. That would make them eligible to be closed as "too broad". But that certainly isn't the case here, as confirmed by multiple subject-matter experts. This one even has a practical, motivating example.